# Will setting permissions on Bitlocker boot partition/drive affect boot?

Tags: windows-vista, boot, bitlocker

I've recently setup a Windows Vista Ultimate machine with Bitlocker encryption. As part of the setup process the [Bitlocker Preparation Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933246) creates a secondary "boot" partition which remains unencrypted. I'd like to change the permissions on the drive so that only Administrators can access it in Windows. Will this any any way affect booting the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No responses so I just tried it. Changing the permissions so that the drive is restricted to Administrators and System did not affect boot.